# Can I create a new object with the results of a query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

If there's a better way to do this, let me know, but this is kind of how i envisioned it. Can it be done?

Customer is a table in the database/datacontext. What I want is to query that table and build a new object with it.

If i were to insert a record, I would do something like this:

```
Customer cust = new Customer(){ FirstName = "A", LastName = "B", Age = 31 }
db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(cust);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

What I want to do is instantiate that object with a query result. Something like this:

```
var query =
     from a in db.Customers
     where a.FirstName == "A"
     select a;

Customer cust = new Customer(){ query };
```

or maybe even

```
Customer cust = new Customer(){
     from a in db.Customers
     where a.FistName == "A"
     select a;
}
```

is there some way to do this?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: are you trying to get 1 customer from the query ?

Comment: yes that. And eventually i'll want to build objects from database information (setting attributes with data from a lookup table). So the next question will probably involve inheriting this object :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, like this:

```
var query =  from c in db.Customers
     where c.FirstName == "somecriteria"
     select new Customer()
     {
        FirstName = "somevalue",
     };
```

you can also make totally anonymous objects as well...

```
var query =  from c in db.Customers
     where c.FirstName == "somecriteria"
     select new() 
     {
        FirstName = c.SomeProperty,
        AnotherProperty=c.AnotherProperty,
     };
```

Comment: Apparently the query returns the same type as the table (which is where the class comes from) so I also found that Customer cust = (from a in db.Customer where a. etc etc); works as well. Add .Single() for one object or do Customer[] to build an object collection. Pretty damn cool. I'm assuming that queries that return a smaller table of results become a child of the table class type.

Comment: you should check out Linqpad, it lets you play around with linq w/o building a full app. it's neet.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Customers
    .Where(x => x.FirstName == "A")
    .Select(x => new Customer{ FirstName =x.FirstName , LastName = x.LastName, Age = x.Age})
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to clone objects in the manner you want

```
db.Customers
    .Where(x => x.FirstName ="A")
    .Select(x => new Customer
        {
           FirstName = x.FirstName,
           LastName = x.LastName,
           ...
           Id = default(x.Id.GetType()) // or copy the Id if you want it
        })
    .First();
```

Besides this method you could add a new Customer constructor that took a Customer as a parameter to do this or add a helper for cloning.

Lastly, you can consider using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for this.